# How to launch process with Fabric

Tags: mysql, fabric

How do you launch a process using [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)?

I'm trying to write a task to reset MySQL's password, which requires I launch the `mysqld_safe` daemon using:

```
sudo bash -c "mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld; chown mysql /var/run/mysqld; mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &"
```

When I run this manually on the server, `ps aux|grep -i mysql` shows it's running just fine, but when I run this using Fabric's `sudo()`, it appears to terminate almost immediately. What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried using `nohup` like:

```
sudo bash -c "mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld; chown mysql /var/run/mysqld; nohup mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &"
```

but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang has a very clear explanation of why that is. Also proposes the solution.

In your case, you should install dtach and run:

```
sudo(dtach -n `mktemp -u /tmp/{0}.XXXX` {1}'.format(some_name, cmd_to_execute))
```

You can drop the "sudo bash" in the beginning btw.